# Different colours for dc.js barchart

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to create a barchart (not rowchart) using d3.js and dc.js.  I can create the bars ok, but they are all the same colour.

I have tried :

- ordinalColors()
- scaleOrdinal.range()
- Renderlet
- colorAccessor

but they all give the one colour for all bars, except colorAccessor which displays no bars at all.

I am using dc.js (version 3.0.2) and d3.js (version 5.4.0) and crossfilter (version 1.3.5).

Could someone please tell me an approach that will work to get different colours on each of my bars please?

Here is my code:

```js
fruits = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "cnt": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "cnt": 15
  },
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "cnt": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "grapefruit",
    "cnt": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "grapefruit",
    "cnt": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "pomegranate",
    "cnt": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "lime",
    "cnt": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "grape",
    "cnt": 50
  }
];

var ndx = crossfilter(fruits);

fruitDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }),
  sumGroup = fruitDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.cnt;
  });

fruitColours = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["red", "yellow", "purple", "pink", "green", "orange", "blue"]);

barChart
  //  .ordinalColors(["red", "yellow", "purple", "pink", "green", "orange", "blue"])
  //  .ordinalColors(fruitColours)
  //  .ordinalColors(["#79CED7", "#66AFB2", "#C96A23", "#D3D1C5", "#F5821F"])
  .width(768)
  .height(380)
  .x(d3.scaleBand())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .xAxisLabel('Fruit')
  .yAxisLabel('Quantity Sold')
  .dimension(fruitDimension)
  .barPadding(0.1)
  .outerPadding(0.05)
  .group(sumGroup)
  .colorAccessor(["#79CED7", "#66AFB2", "#C96A23", "#D3D1C5", "#F5821F", "grey", "purple"])
//     .on("renderlet", function(chart){
//      var colors =d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapefruit", "pomegranate", "lime", "grape"])
//          .range(["steelblue", "brown", "red", "green", "yellow", "grey", "purple"]);
//      chart.selectAll('rect.bar').each(function(d){
////           d3.select(this).attr("style", "fill: " + colors(d.key)); // use key accessor if you are using a custom accessor
//           d3.select(this).attr("style", "fill: " + colors(d.name)); // use key accessor if you are using a custom accessor
//      });
//  });
;

dc.renderAll();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <title>School Donations Dashboard</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/dc.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/keen-dashboards.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.xhtml">Dashboard</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="outer" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Test Bar Chart -->
    <div class="chartWrapper">
      <div class="chartTitle">
        Bar Chart
      </div>
      <div class="chartStage">
        <div id="barChart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Test Bar Chart -->
  </div>
  <!-- /outer -->
  <hr />


  <script src="vendor/js/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor" name="js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor" name="js/crossfilter.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/js/d3-v5.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/js/d3-scale.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/js/dc.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/js/queue.js">
  </script>
  <script src="vendor/js/keen.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="js/graph.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using two libraries with different syntax for 1 chart? I'm not sure how dc syntax works but it seems that these settings are not working togheter, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @DennisSpierenburg, dc.js is built on d3.js - it's sort of a cookbook of reusable charts which you can still customize by "dropping down" to d3 when necessary. That said, it's usually not a good idea to use broad tags when asking about dc.js so I'll remove the d3.js tag.

Comment: @Fintan, yes it's not hard but I don't remember at the moment. Will look up later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem you ran into is confusion between the role of the color accessor ([.colorAccessor()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colorAccessor__anchor)) and the color scale ([.colors()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors__anchor)).

In all dc.js charts, an accessor function will be used to fetch the value that should determine the color. Then this value will be passed through a color scale in order to determine the actual color.

This is handy because for the most part your data is not going to have actual colors in it. The color scale takes some value from your data and maps it to a color.

When you specify the `colorAccessor` you need to give it a function which takes the data supplied by the group, in `{key, value}` form, and extracts the value you want mapped to a color.

If you want to change the colors used, you can use [.colors()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors__anchor), supplying a d3 scale appropriate for your data, or you can use the convenience functions [.ordinalColors()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#ordinalColors__anchor) or [.linearColors()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#linearColors__anchor) and give the colors you want.

That's all you need for most charts. But for stacked charts (bar and line), you also need to specify the color accessor. This is because by default the stack mixin uses the layer (stack name) to key the color:

```
_chart.colorAccessor(function (d) {
    var layer = this.layer || this.name || d.name || d.layer;
    return layer;
});
```

[(source)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/1aa303ccd2fa8631be6c33da49b5f869b62c3a00/src/stack-mixin.js#L321-L324)

So if you want unique colors for each bar, basing the color accessor on the group key is a good bet:

```
chart
    .colorAccessor(d => d.key)
    .ordinalColors(["#79CED7", "#66AFB2", "#C96A23", "#D3D1C5", "#F5821F", "grey", "purple"]);
```

[image: bars with individual colors]
However you'll need to make sure to specify at least as many ordinal colors as there are bars because an ordinal scale will repeat when the domain is larger size than the range.

[Demo fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/kqmw5b0y/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the useful pointers.  This really helps.  Thanks again

Comment: @Gordon. this worked fine! can you point out coloring the bars in case I have a bunch of categories like 100 and I want to color just a select few based on d.key value. 

In this case should I prepare a color array of 100 size by assigning the colors in the order of d.key. ?  if d.key matches my selection, ill give a custom color.. if not ill give a default color. 

or is there a better way to do this like in postRender?

Comment: Hi @MaulikSheth, for cases where you want to insert some logic before the color scale, instead of doing the usual `colorAccessor` + color scale combo, we also have the [colorCalculator](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/ColorMixin.html#colorCalculator), which handles both at once. This [can be useful for a null/undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469274/dc-js-change-default-color-for-undefined-data-in-choropleth-map), and I think it may be helpful for default values too. If you can't figure it out, please ask another question!