# dc.js Change default color for undefined data in choropleth map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm using dc.js for a choropleth map with `dc.geoChoroplethChart()`. Previously with `colorCalculator()`, I can set the default color for null data.

```
chart.colors(colorScale)
     .colorCalculator(
         function (d) { 
             return d === undefined ? '#ddd' : zipChart.colors()(d);
         })
```

The log indicates `colorMixin.colorCalculator` has been deprecated and tell me to use `colorMixin.colors` and `colorMixin.colorAccessor` instead. 
I gave it a try:

```
chart.colors(colorScale)
     .colorAccessor(function (d) {return d;})
```

The map still works but the default color for undefined data is now black. There is only a few [documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html). How can I change it like without `colorCalculator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecating `colorCalculator` function was a mistake and the warning will be removed soon.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1493

I don't like the way the function was implemented, and at the time I thought that scales can do everything that a function can do, but it is simply easier to write a function for this kind of thing.

Sometimes a special case is the best way to deal with an exception to the rule!

Alternately, if you are using a continuous or ordinal color scale, you may be able to use [.unknown()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_unknown) which is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Warning removed in 3.0.11 / 2.1.2