# Color palette is not working in bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

The color palette is not working in the bar chart the way it does in the other charts.

I'm using [this color palette plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/palette.js/master/palette.js).

Comment: Check this thread, or explain your question a little bit more. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871319/automatic-colors-assignment-in-chart-js-2-x-doesnt-work-anymore-used-to-work-i

Comment: Please search SO before posting a new question. This has been asked a few times (although the one posted by @Ahsan is not relevant to dc.js). By default, the dc.js bar chart will use colors for stacks, not for individual bars. Looks like below is the canonical answer for dc.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different colours for dc.js barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774206/different-colours-for-dc-js-barchart)